# WebDeployment - Customize Build Template

Tags: build-automation, workflow-foundation, web-deployment-project

We are using TFS 2010 to deploy a web application. We use the project settings of our web application to configure which iis-folder should be used, to copy the web-application.

That all works great, but we want to copy a missing dll file to the PublishedWebsites folder, that also works, but the copied dll is not in the specified iis-folder.

So can somebody tell me at what point I have to copy the dll?

We are using the worflow-foundation to customize our build-template.

At the moment we are copying the dll directly after the compilation-step.

I hope someone can help us!

Answer (score 0):

You mention that " we want to copy a missing dll file to the PublishedWebsites folder", so you miss something all dll should be there, try to look on my post at the following link:

http://mohamedradwan.wordpress.com/2010/10/23/auto-deploy-your-website-for-qa-with-team-build/

If this didn't help you see my answer on how to include file the the web package at the following link

[How can we include the files created by ajaxmin in the msdeploy package created by MSBuild](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4144472/how-can-we-include-the-files-created-by-ajaxmin-in-the-msdeploy-package-created-b/4166337#4166337)

Thanks

M.Radwan

Comment: The problem is that we use a Registration.dll(library-project). This dll contains a repository.dll. The classes in the repository.dll are not directly used, this means the instances created on runtime by an ioc container and we use only the interfaces instead the classes directly. Therfore the repository.dll is missing after the web-deployment. Localy everything is working as expected but after the automated build the repository.dll is missing. p.s we are using the web-deployment target. Your links dont help me. any other ideas?